# Permutation of 1…9 with no ascending or descending subsequence of length 4

Tags: puzzle, problem-solving, ramsey-theory

Arrange the numbers $1,2,...,9$ in such an order that no four of them appear (adjacently or otherwise) in ascending or descending order. 
Show that there is no arrangement of the numbers $1,2,...,10$ with this property.

Now suppose $n>1$, and find the maximum $k$ such that the numbers $1,2,...,k$ can be arranged with no $n$ of them in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood, this seems like a counter example: 147258396(10). What do you mean by *or otherwise*?

Comment: See the [Erdős-Szekeres theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem).

Comment: @Lepidopterist: I assume it means "subsequences as well". So for example you have 1478 appearing as an ascending subsequence.

Comment: If I'm honest I don't really understand what I'm being asked

Comment: @user61067: it's important that you write that in your question. Explain what you are thinking, otherwise we can't be much help.

Comment: My apologies, I'll make sure I do so in the future

Comment: Do it in the present. Edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

$k = (n - 1)^2$

You need to arrange the $k$ numbers in $n - 1$ groups of $n - 1$ descending elements, where every following group is bigger than the previous.

In the case of $n = 4$ we have

$3\:2\:1\hspace{8 pt}6\:5\:4\hspace{8 pt}9\:8\:7$ or $3$ groups of $3$. Introducing a $10$th element will break the ascending/descending limit of a subsequence, regardless of where it is placed.

Following this logic, we can show that for any $n$ if we take the first $(n - 1)^2$ numbers and arrange them as follows

$\underbrace{\underbrace{n - 1\:\dots\:1}_{n - 1}\hspace{8 pt}\underbrace{2(n - 1)\:\dots\:n}_{n - 1}\:\dots\:\underbrace{(n - 1)(n - 1)\:\dots\:((n - 2)(n - 1) + 1)}_{n - 1}}_{n - 1}$

the maximum length of an ascending/descending subsequence is $n - 1$ (e.g. $n - 1 - 1 + 1 = n - 1$ from the first group) and there is no ascending/descending subsequence of length $n$.

Now if you add a new element, namely the $((n - 1)^2 + 1)$th one, we introduce an ascending/descending subsequence of length $n$ using the logic above. Hence, the maximum for $k$ is $(n - 1)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question consider this sequence $5\ 3\ 7\ 1\ 9\ 4\ 2\ 8\ 6$. None $4$ of them are increasing or decreasing.

Comment: It says to show that you cannot do this with numbers $1,2...,10$ but if I put a $10$ at the end of your sequence...doesn't it work?

Comment: No, then we will have (3,7,9,10)

Comment: Oh I see! so we can pick out any four as long as we keep the order, makes sense now. Thank you both